# error: aggregate std::promise has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Tags: c++, promise, future

I'm trying to to write a code that will use std::promise and std::future.
I wrote a simple main program, but it seems like the compiler doesn't found the std::promise declaration, although I include this file, and able to access this file via Eclipse:

```
//main.cpp
#include <future>

int main()
{
    std::promise<int> promiseObj;
    return 1;
}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
18:17:54 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Test1 ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include\\c++" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o "..\\main.cpp" 
..\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
..\main.cpp:6:23: error: aggregate 'std::promise<int> promiseObj' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
     std::promise<int> promiseObj;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~

18:17:55 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 662ms)
```

When I running other simple program it works fine, I tried to search a lot in the web but I couldn't find an answer.

This is the path for the file:
C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\future

[This is show that I added this path to include path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yFDU.jpg)

I hope that someone will able to assist me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you forget to include `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14` ? I cannot see it in your compilation line `g++ "-IC:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include\\c++" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o "..\\main.cpp"`

Comment: Thanks Werner, I searched a lot for an answer and couldn't find, according to the answer I understand that promise and future are not supported through GCC compiler on windows and only by 3'rd parties libs like boost.

This is so frustrated with C++, when it works on one platform but not on the other.

Comment: But I'm still wondering... How can I know which API is supported in GCC for windows platform and which doesn't?